# Is there a way to configure macos "Hey Siri" trigger delay time?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

[image]

I enabled "Hey Siri" in macOS,  and the keyboard Shortcut is

```
Hold Command Space
```

Can I set the delay time to open it? I want to set a longer time to wake it  than the system default

Comment: You seem to be asking for a way to increase the amount of time you need to hold down Command Space, to trigger Siri. There isn't such an option, but you can always customize the keyboard shortcut. Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish by increasing the trigger time?

Comment: Can't test, but have you looked to see if it's related to the keyboard repeat rate or delay?

Comment: @JBallin  I set my right_option key to command+space to active spotlight, sometimes I accidentally hold for a little longer time, then triggerd siri. there is  a big disturbing black Siri window in the screen, it didn't disappear after a long time,and even can't be close use escape key alone. so,  if there is no simple way to delay the time to trigger siri, maybe I should change siri shortcut to a customize key rather than holding command+space

Comment: What OS? On Big Sur it’s not intrusive.

Comment: Another alternative is to change your shortcut for spotlight, given that may map it to a different key anyway.